# File Creator Program linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, debian

I need to view via terminal in what program the file was created.

Something like :

$ "command" /Volumes/USB1/IMG_0231.jpg

Creator = "Adobe Photoshop Elements 3.0 Macintosh".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not only impossible in general, but also offtopic.

Comment: if you're thinking specifcally about jpg files, it might be possible. Generally, to the level of detail you're describing, you'll have to write your own program. Unix/Linux does have the `file filename` utility, which will output a generic description, like 'shell script', 'c program', 'text data', etc. Good luck.

Comment: there's no general purpose utility for doing this!! files doesn' hold the creator program descriptors...except images or so..

Answer (score 2):

In general this is not possible, because the program that makes the file **should integrate** this information (metadata). And this may not be the case with every program/device/file type.

For file types such as JPEG, made produced by a camera, there is an exif [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data, which can contain quite a lot - geolocation, model, exposure, etc. But if you make a jpeg file, you are responsible for the information. And you may leave it blank.

Another example are the files which contain only text - *.txt, *.sh, *.c, *.cpp etc. They contain only text, and not an additional metadata.

Comment: I am focused on .eps files. For example , if i clicks right mouse button on this file, I can see information about program in which the file was created. That is why , i think, this information is stored somewhere.

Comment: this may help you - http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/

Answer (score 1):

with eps-files you might have success with something like

```
sed -e '/^%%Creator:/!d' -e 's/^%%Creator: *//' MYFILE.EPS
```

this is will only work with EPS-files (and only those that actually have the Creator field set)